# How to switch between Activities in Android using only xml code

Tags: java, android, xml

Hello I have a app im working on that I lost the source code to when my computer crashed I was able to decompile my apk to make it a project again however I need to make a few changes to it so what i need help with is this i have a sliding drawer that has a button in it I want it to open the play store when the user clicks it I know how to do this via a java activity however it only decompiled my code via smali code so I need to know if there is a way to open the play store from a button click via xml

here's my Main code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout android:id="@id/frame" android:focusable="true" android:focusableInTouchMode="true" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <com.d4a.tobiaslauncher.AnimationOnResume android:id="@id/animation_on_resume" android:visibility="gone" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
    <com.d4a.tobiaslauncher.AnimationOpenFolder android:id="@id/animation_open_folder" android:visibility="gone" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
    <LinearLayout android:gravity="center_horizontal" android:orientation="vertical" android:id="@id/folder_container" android:visibility="invisible" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <FrameLayout android:id="@id/folder_title_area" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="1.0dip" android:layout_marginLeft="7.0dip" android:layout_marginRight="7.0dip">
            <EditText android:textSize="36.0dip" android:textColor="#ffffffff" android:gravity="center" android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" android:id="@id/folder_title" android:background="@drawable/folder_title" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="58.0dip" android:includeFontPadding="false" android:inputType="text" android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/caret" />
            <Button android:layout_gravity="right|center" android:id="@id/folder_title_clear" android:background="@drawable/folder_title_xbutton" android:layout_width="19.0dip" android:layout_height="19.0dip" android:layout_marginRight="16.0dip" />
        </FrameLayout>
        <net.suckga.ilauncher.paging.PageScrollView android:id="@id/folder_scroll_container" android:visibility="invisible" android:scrollbars="none" android:fadingEdge="none" android:layout_width="1.0dip" android:layout_height="1.0dip">
            <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal" android:id="@id/folder_scroll_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
        </net.suckga.ilauncher.paging.PageScrollView>
        <com.d4a.tobiaslauncher.PageIndicator android:layout_gravity="bottom" android:id="@id/folder_page_indicator" android:visibility="invisible" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginTop="-17.0dip" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <RelativeLayout android:layout_gravity="top" android:id="@id/springboard_container" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <com.d4a.tobiaslauncher.DockBar android:id="@id/dockBar" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
        <com.d4a.tobiaslauncher.PageIndicator android:id="@id/page_indicator" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_above="@id/dockBar" />
        <net.suckga.ilauncher.paging.PageScrollView android:id="@id/scrollContainer" android:visibility="invisible" android:scrollbars="none" android:fadingEdge="none" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_above="@id/page_indicator">
            <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal" android:id="@id/scrollView" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
        </net.suckga.ilauncher.paging.PageScrollView>  
        <fragment android:name="com.d4a.tobiaslauncher.QuickLaunch"
            android:id="@+id/quicklaunch"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"/>
</RelativeLayout>
    <com.d4a.tobiaslauncher.MovingIconView android:id="@id/panelMoving" android:visibility="gone" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:contentDescription="@null" />
    <LinearLayout android:gravity="center" android:id="@id/logoPanel" android:background="#ff000000" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <ImageView android:id="@id/logo" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/logo" android:contentDescription="@null" />
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Sliding Drawer code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <SlidingDrawer android:id="@id/slidingDrawer" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginBottom="4.0dip" android:handle="@id/handle" android:content="@id/content">
        <ImageView android:id="@id/handle" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="20.0dip" />
        <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical" android:id="@id/content" android:background="@color/drawerbg" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <include android:id="@id/web" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="72.0dip" android:layout_marginLeft="15.0dip" android:layout_marginTop="8.0dip" android:layout_marginRight="15.0dip" android:layout_marginBottom="8.0dip" android:onClick="web" layout="@layout/web_card" />
            <include android:id="@id/mail" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="72.0dip" android:layout_marginLeft="15.0dip" android:layout_marginTop="8.0dip" android:layout_marginRight="15.0dip" android:layout_marginBottom="8.0dip" android:onClick="email" layout="@layout/email_card" />
            <include android:id="@id/musiccard" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="72.0dip" android:layout_marginLeft="15.0dip" android:layout_marginTop="8.0dip" android:layout_marginRight="15.0dip" android:layout_marginBottom="8.0dip" android:onClick="music" layout="@layout/music_card" />
            <include android:id="@id/playcard" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="72.0dip" android:layout_marginLeft="15.0dip" android:layout_marginTop="8.0dip" android:layout_marginRight="15.0dip" android:layout_marginBottom="8.0dip" android:onClick="play" layout="@layout/playstore_card" />
            <include android:layout_gravity="center" android:id="@id/buttons" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" layout="@layout/buttons2" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </SlidingDrawer>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Playstore Button card:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout android:background="@drawable/card_background" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:onClick="play"
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <ImageView android:id="@id/playicon" android:padding="5.0dip" android:layout_width="68.0dip" android:layout_height="68.0dip" android:src="@drawable/play" android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
    <TextView android:textSize="30.0sp" android:textColor="@color/cardText" android:id="@id/play" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Google Play" android:layout_toRightOf="@id/playicon" android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

any help would be awesome

Thanks way in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do this with **only** XML code. You **must** create an `OnClickListener` or declare a `onClick` method and start the Activity in Java.

Comment: I would but my code is in smail format any other way to get passed this issue? thanks :)

Comment: @appd3vs What part of "You cannot do this" did you not understand?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding your question. If so, I'm sorry, please let me know, and I'll change my answer.

But if you have a button and you want to go to a different activity it is very simple.

Simply add:

```
android:onClick="functionName"
```

to the XML of the button.

Then in your java, create a function called functionName that takes View view as a parameter and then create an intent to the new activity and start it.

```
public void functionName(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplication(),classToGoTo.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Or however else you want to go to that other activity. Or whatever else you want to do. Just put it inside of the functionName function.

I hope this helps. Good luck :)

Comment: I would do that however my java classes are in smali format any other ideas??